# SELENIUM (Python) : How to retrieve the URL to which an element redirects me to (opens a new tab) after clicking? Element has <a> tag but no href

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a [website](https://es.wallapop.com/app/search?category_ids=17000&keywords=bicicletas) with product listings that if clicked on redirect the user to a new tab with further information/contact the seller details. I am trying to retrieve said URL without actually having to click on each listing in the catalog and wait for the page to load as this would take a lot of time.

I have searched in web inspector for the "href" but the only link available is to the image source of each listing. However, I noticed that after clicking each element, a GET request method gets sent and this is the URL (https://api.wallapop.com/api/v3/items/v6g2v4y045ze?language=es) it contains pretty much all the information I need, I'm not sure if it's of any use, but its the furthest I've gotten.

**UPDATE**: I tried the code I was suggested (with modifications to specifically find the 'href' attributes in the clickable elements), but I get **None** returning. I have been looking into finding an 'onclick' element or something similar that might have what I'm looking for but so far it looks like the solution will end up being clicking each element and extracting all the information from there.

```py
elements123 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class,"ItemCardList__item")]')
for e in elements123:
    print(e.get_attribute('href'))
```

I appreciate any insights, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")

# Get all the elements available with tag name 'a'
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
for e in elements:
    print(e.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get **None** returning. I might be overshooting, but I'm hoping that perhaps I can find a way to manipulate the API URL to get the desired information. But I haven't been able to get it down yet. I might just have to click on every listing in the end

Comment: It's possible the element might be using javascripts onclick Event. Try check the `onclick` attribute on the element. The value will be javascript code, or a javascript function call

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I did it. but no, is it possible there isn't even a link but rather the clicking simply just sends a request to an internal API?